# приватный метод область видимости

Tags: php, ооп

```
namespace user\login\SystemCommand;

class Command extends SystemCommand
{
    ...
    private function transaction (){
        ...
        $date = new DateTime();
        $date->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString('yesterday'));
        $time =  $date->format(\DateTime::RFC3339);
        ...
    }
    ...

    echo $this->yad_transaction();
}
```

Почему возникает ошибка 
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'user\login\SystemCommand\DateTime' not found in ...

Comment: `$date = new \DateTime();` - добавьте слэш

Comment: @splash58, а можете объяснить что он означает?

Comment: насколько я понимаю, глобальное пространство имен. Сейчас класс ищется в вашем